# Assigning Case manager in Drupal Webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm having an issue assigning a Case Manager in a Drupal CiviCRM-webform when Case Type is set  to  user select. Does any one know how I can go about this?

CiviCRM 4.6.19
Drupal  7.44

Please see attached screen shots which show what happens when the case type is set to user select.
Thanks
[image: Case type defined]

[image: Case type set to user select]

Comment: Hi Alice - please provide more detail about the issue - e.g. list the exact steps by which you are trying to assign a case manager and whether are you receiving an error message? If you are receiving an error message, please provide the detail of that message - this will help someone provide you with a more direct response. Kind regards, Tamar

Comment: A screnshot of the CiviCRM tab of your webform (the case sub-tab) would help.

Comment: Hi Tamar- Thanks for your reply. There's no error message. I am trying to assign a case manager to all cases opened through the webform using the case coordinator (case manager) field. If the case type is set this works however if case type is set to user select, case coordinator (case manager) cannot be assigned. I have upgraded the site this morning but this didnt make a difference.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the available options to select a case manager whether the case type is defined or whether it is set to be user select. There are three choices: user select, automatic, and contact 1 (if you have more than one contact defined in the form you can choose any contact to be the case manager). If I know who I want the case manager to be I add a contact to the form specifically for that purpose, define the 'Existing contact' field to be my target named contact, and simply hide the form field so the user doesn't even see it.

Comment: Hi Graham,  Thanks for your reply. That is what I have done however you will noticed that the case manager field only appears when the case type is defined and therefore cannot be set when it is set to user select.